# How to Input my Training Data into this Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to solve a classification problem with a specific piece of code, and I'm having trouble understanding exactly how my data is to be fed into the Neural Network.

I started encoding the data using 1-of-C dummy-encoding so I can preserve categorical context in the data. I haven't finished encoding the data completely as I don't fully understand how to utilize the code at hand for input.

Here is a sample of my encoded data thus far:

```
'In Raw format, for predicting Political Party Affiliation
   'Age Sex     Income    Area      Party
[0] 30  male    38000.00  urban     democrat
[1] 36  female  42000.00  suburban  republican
[2] 52  male    40000.00  rural     independent
[3] 42  female  44000.00  suburban  other

'Encoded Format
[0] -1.23  -1.0  -1.34  ( 0.0   1.0)  (0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0)
[1] -0.49   1.0   0.45  ( 1.0   0.0)  (0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0)
[2]  1.48  -1.0  -0.45  (-1.0  -1.0)  (0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0)
[3]  0.25   1.0   1.34  ( 1.0   0.0)  (1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0)
```

I used Gaussian Normalization for the numeric data, 1-of-C dummy-encoding, and 1-of-(C-1) encoding for the String data. The last column of data are the categories.

Taking the code below into consideration; the Input Variable X accepts data in the following format:

```
X=np.array([[1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]])
```

Do I input my data like so until I've looped through all of it?

```
X=np.array([[-1.23,-1,-1.34,0010],[00000010,-.49,1,.45],[1000,00001000,1.48,-1]])
```

I've read the following SO question: [How is input dataset fed into neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201220/how-is-input-dataset-fed-into-neural-network) that has helped clarify the process. How features should be fed in row by row, with the Target feature/Label (political party in this case) as the last feature per row. This makes sense to me. In the code posted I'm assuming that the Variable Y is the target.

With that in mind, should my input be this:

```
X=np.array([[-1.23,-1,-1.34,0010],[00000010,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
```

Where I only capture the first row, with Target feature as the last input?

I'm not sure which one it should be. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
import numpy as np

#Input array
 X=np.array([[1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]])

#Output
 y=np.array([[1],[1],[0]])

#Sigmoid Function
 def sigmoid (x):
 return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

#Derivative of Sigmoid Function
 def derivatives_sigmoid(x):
 return x * (1 - x)

#Variable initialization
 epoch=5000 #Setting training iterations
 lr=0.1 #Setting learning rate
 inputlayer_neurons = X.shape[1] #number of features in data set
 hiddenlayer_neurons = 3 #number of hidden layers neurons
 output_neurons = 1 #number of neurons at output layer

#weight and bias initialization
 wh=np.random.uniform(size=(inputlayer_neurons,hiddenlayer_neurons))
 bh=np.random.uniform(size=(1,hiddenlayer_neurons))
 wout=np.random.uniform(size=(hiddenlayer_neurons,output_neurons))
 bout=np.random.uniform(size=(1,output_neurons))

for i in range(epoch):

#Forward Propogation
 hidden_layer_input1=np.dot(X,wh)
 hidden_layer_input=hidden_layer_input1 + bh
 hiddenlayer_activations = sigmoid(hidden_layer_input)
 output_layer_input1=np.dot(hiddenlayer_activations,wout)
 output_layer_input= output_layer_input1+ bout
 output = sigmoid(output_layer_input)

#Backpropagation
 E = y-output
 slope_output_layer = derivatives_sigmoid(output)
 slope_hidden_layer = derivatives_sigmoid(hiddenlayer_activations)
 d_output = E * slope_output_layer
 Error_at_hidden_layer = d_output.dot(wout.T)
 d_hiddenlayer = Error_at_hidden_layer * slope_hidden_layer
 wout += hiddenlayer_activations.T.dot(d_output) *lr
 bout += np.sum(d_output, axis=0,keepdims=True) *lr
 wh += X.T.dot(d_hiddenlayer) *lr
 bh += np.sum(d_hiddenlayer, axis=0,keepdims=True) *lr

print output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great question.

First off use pre-built Neural Network implementations from [SciKit Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier)

Next, split your data in to features and labels (flatten your input vector first)

```
X_features=X[:,:-1]
X_labels=X[:,-1]
```

Then setup the SciKit MLP

```
model=MLPClassifier(args...)
```

Fit your data

```
model.fit(X_features,X_labels)
```

Voila...

Now you can predict a new input with

```
Y=model.predict(input_vector)
```

Nb: in the name of true data science remember to split your data in to a training and verification set (eg 90/10)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using SciKit. For reasons associated with a limited development environment (watered down Python Library), I wanted to try and utilize the code I posted above. If you think that the code is inadequate for what I'm trying to accomplish, then perhaps I can try contacting the IT dept. for access to such libraries. I'm trying to avoid that however.

Comment: They're probably not inadequate. I haven't studied your implementation in detail, I was just trying to cut a corner.

Comment: The method still applies though. Flatten the input vector. Separate in feature and labels and then iteratively train